# GDB disassembly uses inconsistent register naming

Tags: debugging, assembly, gdb, disassembly

I'm debugging/disassembling a very simply C program I wrote just for learning purposes. However, I notice that GDB appears to be using inconsistent notation for the registers between the disassembled output and what it tells me when I enter "info registers" after a breakpoint.

Here is part of the disassembled output (around my breakpoint):

```
0x0000000100000d15 <main+181>:  xor    %dl,%dl
0x0000000100000d17 <main+183>:  mov    %ecx,%edi
0x0000000100000d19 <main+185>:  mov    %dl,%al
0x0000000100000d1b <main+187>:  callq  0x100000da0 <checkLicense>
0x0000000100000d20 <main+192>:  mov    %eax,%ecx
0x0000000100000d22 <main+194>:  cmp    $0x0,%ecx
0x0000000100000d25 <main+197>:  je     0x100000d47 <main+231>
0x0000000100000d27 <main+199>:  lea    0x1bb(%rip),%rax        # 0x100000ee9
0x0000000100000d2e <main+206>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
```

And here is part of the output I get when I call the "info registers" command in GDB:

```
(gdb) info registers
rax            0x1  1
rbx            0x0  0
rcx            0x1  1
rdx            0x1  1
rsi            0x3  3
rdi            0x3  3
```

I set my breakpoint where the cmp operation occurs. As you can see it is comparing the value in register ECX to 0, however, it doesn't appear that ECX is a real register. When I get the result of "info registers" it does appear to return real registers, namely rcx. When I try to manipulate the registers in GDB using "set $ecx = 1" for example, it has no effect, however when I do "set $rcx = 1", it does seem to work.

What's up with this inconsistency and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> What's up with this inconsistency?

The instruction `cmp $0x0,%ecx` compares *lower 32-bits* of register `rcx` with `0`, so the disassembly is correct.

> "info registers" it does appear to return real registers, namely rcx

Correct.

> "set $ecx = 1" for example, it has no effect

It does have effect for me:

```
(gdb) info reg rcx
rcx            0xffffffffffffffff   -1
(gdb) set $ecx = 0
(gdb) info reg rcx
rcx            0xffffffff00000000   -4294967296
```

If `set $ecx = 1` really has no effect for you, it might be a GDB bug.